# Search result put filter box

Tags: magento2, css

any idea why in search result the filter box goes below the catalog listing?
is there a way to fix that[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check Layout file of Catalog Search Result page.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Make sure your page layout is **2columns-left**